# Canvas draw shapes on the go

Tags: html, html5-canvas, draw

When I run it the browser loads for a while and then displays the whole canvas. How can I make it display as soon as it finishes one loop iteration?And why is this code not doing what I expect it to?

This is my code:

```
  for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<50;j++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillRect(10*j, 10*i, 10, 10);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+')';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        sleep(10);
    }
  }


function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
      }
   }
 }
```

OK... I managed to achieve the desired effect using

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

However can someone please explain why the code above behaves the way it does? Why does it draw all 2500 shapes before it displays the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use requestAnimationFrame

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/NRBy5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var RAF;
    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    function animate() {

      // draw stuff
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillRect(10*j, 10*i, 10, 10);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+','+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+')';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();


      // update
      j+=1;
      console.log(i+"/"+j);
      if(j>=50){
          i+=1;
          j=0;
          if(i>=50){
              cancelAnimationFrame(RAF);
          }
      }

      // request new frame
      RAF=requestAnimationFrame(function() { animate(); });

    }
    animate();


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not draw as it loads that is the point. I am building a raytracer and I want to display each pixel as it is computed. Sleep is there to simulate some calculations taking place for each pixel.

Comment: What am I missing...  **The sleep is causing the effect your question asks to eliminate.** By the time your browser is done sleeping all your rectangles have been drawn.  Sleep behaves the way you have coded it when sleeps are nested--they accumulate!  Good work on requestAnimationFrame,  I was just coding up a solution like that for you.

Comment: I have put the sleep function up. I imagined that the program would not exit the loop before finishing sleep. Therefore it should draw a square, wait for sleep, draw second square, wait for sleep. Imagine I had a loop iterating to 10k instead of sleep the code should behave the same way. However it would still wait till all iterations are done and then dispaly the whole canvas. Why does it do that?

Comment: Keep in mind that sleep(10) just puts the **UI thread** to sleep for 10ms.  Your rectangle drawings have all been sent off to a **GPU thread** for calculation and compositing.  So the GPU calculating is being **done simultaneously** with the sleeping.  The net effect is the GPU calculates all your rectangles FAST--in 2-3ms and it's done.  Then your repeated calls to sleep keep the canvas UI thread from drawing your completed rectangle collage until your piled up sleeps are complete.

Comment: If you want your "pixels" to draw in an efficient and evenly-timed way, you can wrap requestAnimationFrame in a setTimeout.  This will get you all the "modern" benefits of requestAnimationFrame plus the asynchronous even-timing of setTimeout.  Check out this great article on combining RAF+setTimeout:  http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/